# Multi-index searches without Solr?

Tags: search

I'm struggling to set up a decent search using Search API. By "decent" I mean a small block that performs a multi-index search (nodes and taxonomy terms). I want to free visitor from defining what they want to search through, instead I want to provide a no-brainer which does the search and displays results in categorized, paged manner.

Even though I installed the multi-index submodule, when creating a search apge, I'm still limited to select one index. Then I found kind of confirmation in the README file that currently only Solr can take advantage of that. So the question is: is it possible to create a multi-index search without Solr?

Answer (score 1):

Only Solr supports that functionality. What you need is:

1. Create a server in Search API, call it, for example, "solr_server".
2. Create two indexes, one for nodes another for taxonomies. Make sure both indexes belong to "solr_server"
3. In views (make sure that search_api_views module is enabled), select 'solr_server' from Show dropdown list.
4. Now you can add fields from every index, that belongs to "solr_server".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Current dev version of [Search API multi-index searches](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_multi) can make multi-index searches for any server, not only Solr.